# C++ : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 since upgrading to Mountain lion

Tags: c++, xcode, osx-mountain-lion

I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't find a clear answer to the issue. I have just upgraded from Mac OSX 10.5 to 10.8, and at the same time xcode from 3.x to 4.6 and now some of my code which compiled on 10.5 is no longer compiling. With errors of the form:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "MultiTerminator::MultiTerminator(std::vector, std::allocator > >&)", referenced from:
>         _main in ccqxAVll.o
>     "vtable for MultiTerminator", referenced from:
>         MultiTerminator::~MultiTerminator()in ccqxAVll.o
>     NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I can provide code but I'm pretty sure this not a code issue but rather some installation issue. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: Yeah cleaned and rebuilt same issue...

Comment: Is `MultiTerminator` part of your own source code or is it from some library?

Comment: Did you install the command line tools from Xcode preferences?